# Merging multiple data rows and binning data into time intervals

Tags: r, data-binding, combinations, binning

I have a dataset which contains information on bee in- and out-activity along with weight and temperature for beehives. Unfortunately, the different data was collected at slightly different times so now I have rows containing data for some attributes but NA for others and need to merge them together. I want to pool the data together in 15 minute intervals which should ensure each interval has data for everything, and discard any NA information. If there is more than one set of data for in/out activity I would want to SUM it, while for weight and temperature I would want to average it. I am new to R so have no clue how to do this.

[image: Data snapshot]

An example of my data is following:

```
DateTime                Temp   Weight   In     Out 
29/09/2022 11:30        <NA>    <NA>    220    210
29/09/2022 11:30        61.22   49.22  <NA>    <NA>
29/09/2022 11:43        62.02   <NA>    211    156
29/09/2022 11:45        <NA>    48.99   <NA>   <NA>
29/09/2022 11:46        62.33   <NA>    133    155
```

What I want to combine the data to look like:

```
 DateTime                Temp    Weight   In    Out 
 29/09/2022 11:30        61.62   49.22    431   366
 29/09/2022 11:45        62.33   48.99    133   155
```

Any suggestions very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- tibble::tribble(
  ~DateTime, ~Temp, ~Weight, ~In, ~Out, 
  "29/09/2022 11:30", NA_real_, NA_real_, 220, 210,
  "29/09/2022 11:30", 61.22, 49.22,  NA_real_, NA_real_,
  "29/09/2022 11:43", 62.02, NA_real_, 211, 156,
  "29/09/2022 11:45", NA_real_, 48.99, NA_real_, NA_real_,
  "29/09/2022 11:46", 62.33, NA_real_, 133, 155
)

library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

df1 |> 
  mutate(
    # Setting datetime variable to datetime format
    DateTime = parse_date_time(DateTime, orders = "dmy HM"),
    # Setting the 15 minute intervals
    intervals = case_when(minute(DateTime) < 15 ~ 0,
                          minute(DateTime) < 30 ~ 15,
                          minute(DateTime) < 45 ~ 30,
                          TRUE ~ 45),
    # Setting the DateTime variable into 15 minute groups
    DateTime = paste(year(DateTime), month(DateTime), day(DateTime), hour(DateTime), intervals) |> 
      parse_date_time(orders = "ymd HM")) |> 
  # Setting the grouping to summarize by
  group_by(DateTime) |> 
  # Summarize as desired
  summarize(across(c(Temp, Weight), mean, na.rm = TRUE),
            across(c(In, Out), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) |> 
  # Remove the grouping
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 2 × 5
  DateTime             Temp Weight    In   Out
  <dttm>              <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2022-09-29 11:30:00  61.6   49.2   431   366
2 2022-09-29 11:45:00  62.3   49.0   133   155
```